# How to properly use UUID as @PathVariable to hide sensitive data? REST API w/ Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mariadb, spring-restcontroller

I have this basic delete request:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteSubscription(@PathVariable Long id) {
    subscriptionService.deleteSubscription(id);

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

So I was told this is not ok because sensitive data (the id) gets exposed and a better way would be to use UUID but how to do it?

I am using Spring Data JPA, MariaDB.

I don't know how to really do it. The UUID must be the primary key to replace the id or some sort of generated & validated value?

Comment: Does the ID really mean anything? Like a staff number or Bank account, for example? Or is the ID just a consecutive, randomly assigned number?

Comment: Simply generated by the database, starting from 1 to n. It means nothing more than a unique identifier.

Comment: Instead of using UUIDs, which requires changing your data model, you could encode/decode your ids using [Squids](https://sqids.org/).

Comment: If the number is simply generated by the database, I can't see why a UUID should be more secure. Neither the ID nor the UUID allow conclusions to be drawn about the user of the application?

Comment: A consecutive ID exposes how many of the thing exists, which might be interesting to some parties.

Comment: @AndrewS That is an argument. However, you could also start with a larger starting value or increase the step size to confuse your enemies.

Comment: I found an interesting topic here: https://medium.com/lightrail/prevent-business-intelligence-leaks-by-using-uuids-instead-of-database-ids-on-urls-and-in-apis-17f15669fd2e

Comment: the "security issue" with sequential integer ids is not that it will expose counts (although that article claims it is lol), it's that it allows easy guessing. If you give an attacker 1234, its easy to know that 1233 and 1235, etc. are likely valid and adjacent records where as with guids, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

**Security**:

Whether a uuid or a serial number should be used for security reasons depends on the requirements - which only you know. Any answer from this would be opinion based.

Also consider that MariaDB uses UUID type 1 (timestamp based), where timestamps can be extracted.

**Technial aspects**:

A serial (auto_increment) number should always be preferred over a UUID:

- 16 bytes for uuid (compared to 4 or 8 bytes using a serial number)
- cannot be sorted naturally
- MariaDB < 10.7 doesn't have UUID data type, so you need to unhex it before you can store it as 16 bytes instead of a 36 byte char.
- Indexing is much more complex and slower (see [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/))
- Statement based replication doesn't work with UUID().

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the criticism is that usually the id is the primary key and it's a sequential number. Now, if you have, say, a user with an id of 1234, then a hacker will likely know that there must have been valid ids preceding your id, like 1233, 1232, etc. So, a malicious user might try to issue delete commands sequentially for those numbers and you rely on your extra layers of security in order to avoid actually executing those commands.

So, if you have [UUID](https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/definition/UUID-Universal-Unique-Identifier), randomly generated for all users and ensuring that it's unique, then a hacker would have no information what UUIDs are valid and which are not, so his efforts would mostly be in vain as the requests he would spend his resources upon would try to remove items that do not even exist. Your system could detect users/IP addresses, etc. that attempt to remove UUIDs that do not exist and block them.

Then your action can search for the entity by UUID, see [FindByUUID() using Spring Data's JPA Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350154/findbyuuid-using-spring-datas-jpa-repository)

make further validations, as of whether the action is valid to be issued by the user with the UUID passed and if so, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical auto-incremented ids are vulnerable to [IDOR](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html): if your app doesn't handle authorisation well enough, hackers could get access to unauthorised resources by trying out other ids.

AFAIK, only UUID ***v4*** can help making URLs *unguessable*, but a proper authorisation layer is still needed anyways (UUIDs can leak).

I tend to use both ids in my SQL tables: auto-incremented IDs for technical internal PKs (hence referenced by FKs), plus a UUID (v4) with a unique index used in HTTP traffic for instance.

But, never without an authorisation layer, i.e. something that answers "*is the request allowed to access this resource?*".

---

Interesting related reads:

- The [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#page-16) itself:

> Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess; they should not be used as security capabilities

- This [article](https://versprite.com/blog/universally-unique-identifiers/) from VerSprite, which explains the several versions of UUIDs.